# NodeJS: Reliably act upon a closed stream

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm looking for a way to reliably know for sure whether all the data in the stream has been processed. An asynchronous `data` listener might be called *after* the `end` event, in which case I cannot use the `end` event to, for instance, close a database connection when the `data` event is still executing database queries.

Example:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const stream = fs.createReadStream('./big.file', { encoding: 'utf8' });

stream
  .on('data', () => {
    stream.pause();
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('data');
      stream.resume();
    }, 10);
  })
  .on('close', function() {
    console.log('end');
  });
```

This will log "data" a lot of times, then "end", and then "data" one more time.

So in a real-world example, if "data" is doing queries, and "end" would close the connection, the last query would throw an error because the database connection was closed prematurely.

I've noticed a `closed` property on the stream, and of course there is the `isPaused()` methods, and I can use those to fix my problem kind of:

```js
stream
  .on('data', () => {
    stream.pause();
    databaseQuery().then(result => {
      stream.resume();

      if (stream.closed) {
        closeConnection();
      }
    });
  })
  .on('close', function() {
    if (!stream.isPaused()) {
      closeConnection();
    }
  });
```

I'm unsure however if this is the best way to go about this. 
Can I be sure the connection will be closed at all?

**Edit**: I'm seeing similar results for the "end" event, it doesn't matter whether I use "end" or "close", the test logs are identical.

Comment: Based on the node docs, the `end` event should emit when no more data is available for consumption https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

Comment: Sorry, you're right, but I'm seeing similar results when using `end` instead of `close`.

Comment: Why the use of `setTimeout`? The `data` event will emit, but you won't console.log it until 10 ms after the event has already emitted. This means the `end` (or even `close`) event will emit and `console.log('end')` before the data event consoles. Basically, the setTimeout is the cause for why you see different ordering in your console.logs

Comment: `setTimeout` is used as a proof of concept. My actual script executes database queries, which are also asynchronous.

Comment: Ah I see. What seems a little weird to me is the database query is within the data event handler. Where I thought it'd be the reverse, where a database query results are piped to a readable stream or if the results are already a readable stream, you then attach the event handlers on to the resulting stream. Maybe someone with more know-how will pop in to answer this

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, like piping the rows of the file to a stream of database query objects? That makes sense actually... But still, it would be difficult to have a canonical "end" event where I'm sure all database query promises have resolved.